# IOS Unknown crash :- BUG IN CLIENT OF LIBPLATFORM: Trying to recursively lock an os_unfair_lock

Tags: ios, swift, crash, crashlytics

Here is the code where the crash had occurred :-

```
private func dispatchMessageImmediately(topicName : String, mqttMessage : MQTTMessage){
        AppDelegate.getAppDelegate().log.debug("Message: \(String(describing: mqttMessage.payloadString))")
        let listener = self.topicToListenerMap?[topicName]

        if listener != nil {
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                MessageDispatchUtils.dispatchMessageToListeners(topicName: topicName, mqttMessage: mqttMessage, topicListener: listener!)
            })
        }
}
```

The Xcode version I am using is 9.3. My os version is iOS 11.4.1 Device is iPhone 5s. The crash is caused in libswift.dylib

Here is the crash report for the crash.Any help? Thanks in advance

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_platform.dylib       0x18358de38 _os_unfair_lock_recursive_abort + 36
1  libsystem_platform.dylib       0x18358ebb8 _os_unfair_lock_lock_slow + 264
2  libobjc.A.dylib                0x182b45720 objc_object::sidetable_clearDeallocating() + 104
3  libobjc.A.dylib                0x182b349d8 objc_destructInstance + 140
4  libswiftCore.dylib             0x10263ec0c swift_deallocClassInstance + 32
5  libswiftCore.dylib             0x10263eb4c _swift_release_dealloc + 28
6  Razorpay                       0x1020f09b0 _T08Razorpay0A13UtilFunctionsC24handleUnhandledExceptionys5Int32V16havingSignalCode_SS03andI4NametFZTf4nnd_n + 248
7  libsystem_platform.dylib       0x183590b48 _sigtramp + 36
8  libobjc.A.dylib                0x182b45740 objc_object::sidetable_clearDeallocating() + 136
9  libobjc.A.dylib                0x182b45740 objc_object::sidetable_clearDeallocating() + 136
10 libobjc.A.dylib                0x182b349d8 objc_destructInstance + 140
11 libswiftCore.dylib             0x10263ec0c swift_deallocClassInstance + 32
12 libswiftCore.dylib             0x10263eb4c _swift_release_dealloc + 28
13 libswiftCore.dylib             0x1025750ec specialized String.debugDescription.getter + 4580
14 libswiftCore.dylib             0x1024bd66c protocol witness for CustomDebugStringConvertible.debugDescription.getter in conformance String + 290904
15 libswiftCore.dylib             0x1023da008 _debugPrint_unlocked<A, B>(_:_:) + 252544
16 libswiftCore.dylib             0x10257bc04 specialized _debugPrint<A>(_:separator:terminator:to:) + 31996
17 libswiftCore.dylib             0x10245a8fc Optional.debugDescription.getter + 68296
18 libswiftCore.dylib             0x10245aa4c protocol witness for CustomStringConvertible.description.getter in conformance <A> A! + 68632
19 libswiftCore.dylib             0x10257bf44 specialized _print_unlocked<A, B>(_:_:) + 32828
20 Quickride                      0x10090c37c implicit closure #1 in EventServiceProxy.dispatchMessageImmediately(topicName:mqttMessage:) (EventServiceProxy.swift:238)
21 Quickride                      0x1009186c4 partial apply for implicit closure #1 in EventServiceProxy.onNewMessageArrived(mqttMessage:) + 4314498756
22 XCGLogger                      0x1021b86f4 _T09XCGLoggerAAC5loglnyAB5LevelO_SS12functionNameSS04fileE0Si10lineNumbers10DictionaryVySSypG8userInfoypSgyc7closuretFTf4ngXgXnggn_n + 232
23 XCGLogger                      0x1021b3bac _T09XCGLoggerAAC7verboseyypSgyXK_s12StaticStringV12functionNameAF04fileF0Si10lineNumbers10DictionaryVySSypG8userInfotFTm + 500
24 XCGLogger                      0x1021b2aa8 _T09XCGLoggerAAC5debugyypSgyXK_s12StaticStringV12functionNameAF04fileF0Si10lineNumbers10DictionaryVySSypG8userInfotF + 32
25 Quickride                      0x100915144 specialized EventServiceProxy.dispatchMessageImmediately(topicName:mqttMessage:) (EventServiceProxy.swift:238)
26 Quickride                      0x100916918 specialized EventServiceProxy.onNewMessageArrived(mqttMessage:) (EventServiceProxy.swift:145)
27 Quickride                      0x10090d8c8 protocol witness for MqttCallback.onNewMessageArrived(mqttMessage:) in conformance EventServiceProxy (EventServiceProxy.swift)
28 Quickride                      0x100cf309c specialized closure #1 in closure #4 in EventServiceConnection.createMqttConfig() (EventServiceConnection.swift:100)
 29 Quickride                      0x100cf29f4 partial apply for closure #1 in closure #4 in EventServiceConnection.createMqttConfig() (EventServiceConnection.swift)
 30 Quickride                      0x1008c19fc thunk for @callee_owned () -> () (RideManagementModuleSessonHandler.swift)
 31 libdispatch.dylib              0x183260aa0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
 32 libdispatch.dylib              0x183260a60 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
 33 libdispatch.dylib              0x18326d65c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1012
 34 CoreFoundation                 0x183917070 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
 35 CoreFoundation                 0x183914bc8 __CFRunLoopRun + 2272
 36 CoreFoundation                 0x183834da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific +    552
 37 GraphicsServices               0x18581a020 GSEventRunModal + 100
 38 UIKit                          0x18d854758 UIApplicationMain + 236
 39 Quickride                      0x1007d4bf0 main (AppDelegate.swift:26)
 40 libdyld.dylib                  0x1832c5fc0 start + 4
```

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the issue or is it some crash logs that you got from app store?

Comment: @KarthickRamesh I am not able to reproduce the issue. The crash report I got it from the crashlytics. Any idea why such kind of crash occur ?

Comment: Is it a de-symbolicated crash log?

Comment: Without the code that's involved in the crash it's hard to tell.

Comment: @KarthickRamesh Yes

Comment: @Cristik I will attach the part of the code where the crash had occurred

Comment: @Cristik I have the attached the code where the crash had occurred. any help?

Comment: @KarthickRamesh I have attached the code where the crash had occurred . any help?

Comment: You posted a couple of lines of code, what's the actual line where the crash happens? Please don't give us bits by bits of information, that's not gonna help you or us.

Comment: @Cristik This is the line at which the crash occurred  AppDelegate.getAppDelegate().log.debug("Message: \(String(describing: mqttMessage.payloadString))")

Comment: Your Application Name is QuickRide? what is razorPay?

Comment: @KarthickRamesh Yes my application name is Quickride . Razorpay is payment gateway

Comment: To get my self a context on what you are trying, on success of some service call, you are trying to send a message after getting a reference of app delegate. You are using MessageDispatchUtils and calling dispatchMessageToListeners in main thread. If my understanding is correct can you also share the ALL THE code that dispatchMessageToListeners calls.

Comment: look at line no 7. there is a UNIX signal. I guess some memory issue on another thread.

Comment: you dropped out some important information from crash report. there is no reason why your app is crashed.

Comment: @HarvantS.Choudhary I have attached all the report clearly. Can you let me know what I that unix signal? Why can it be caused?. Thanks in advance

Comment: thats the information which is missing, you can find it in your crash report. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744385/interpreting-iphone-crash-log-stack-trace check here.

Comment: in your app you have tried to get access to some memory address you are not authorised for. system bounced you back and result is crash.

Comment: @HarvantS.Choudhary Any idea on how to find and fix the problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: The part of the code also I have attached @HarvantS.Choudhary

Comment: @HarvantS.Choudhary thanks a lot for the help